# Wordpress widget display issue

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to display widget by code instead of placing in a specific widget area?

I have a custom page in my wp application. I want to display a widget on this page? Can I do that? If yes How?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out my plugin, Widget Instance, http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-instance.

You can add specific widgets configured in Appearance > Widgets within the wysiwyg editor. My plugin provides an editor button with a select menu of all the widgets added to sidebars for you to choose from.